# change security policy in milo opc example server

Tags: opc, opc-ua, milo

How to change security policy in milo example server? I've tried to connect to milo's opc server with UaExpert, and set the security policy. No matter what security policy I choose, the result is the same error:

```
    ERROR o.e.m.o.s.s.t.u.UascServerAsymmetricHandler - [remote=/127.0.0.1:33762] Exception caught; sent ErrorMessage{error=StatusCode{name=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, value=0x80130000, quality=bad}, reason=certificate path validation failed}
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: UaException: status=Bad_SecurityChecksFailed, message=certificate path validation failed
```

How can I configure it correctly?

Second question: The example server seems quite complicated. What is the simplest way to create a server and connect to it? Is there a minimal example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow

I do not know the Milo server and I have not almost used  UAExpert but:

The client must trust the server certificate and the server must do the same with the client's certificate and of course both sides must have their certificate, sometimes the client and the server automatically create one if it doesn't exist but sometimes it should be created previously by external ways.

Help about UAExpert http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uaexpert/1.4.3/html/first_steps.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with certificates then choose then endpoint with SecurityPolicy None when connecting:

[image: UaExpert]

Otherwise, note the security directory the example server logs on startup. Something like:

```
INFO  o.e.m.examples.server.ExampleServer - security temp dir: /var/folders/1v/2pxlxd_x4bsdxz25_fv7r0940000gn/T/security
```

Navigate to the security directory and you'll find the UaExpert client certificate in the `pki/rejected` folder. You can move it to `pki/trusted/certs` and then connect with security from UaExpert.

Comment: I dont know why but before this question I did not see any certs, I knew that this is the way but I could not find it. what about next question kevin, what is the simplest way to create server, I do not get the ExampleServer code, I found it such a complex one and I feel that there could be a simpler example to run server and do  test against it.

Comment: ExampleServer isn’t that complex. You can simplify it further by removing things like certificate handling and identity validation. And maybe have a simpler endpoint configuration. But these things are all important to demonstrate.